# MICROSOFT DYNAMICS CRM 2011 installation

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

1133
I'm installing MS DYNAMICS 2011 fresh on MS2012 webserver and I keep getting this error:
Action Microsoft Crm Setup Server Configure Web Server Action failed. A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070520) RETRY CANCEL are my only options? I'm installing the app as a service acct will ADMIN privs in AD.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Read what you've submitted aloud and see if it makes any sense.

Comment: the litteral exception is >> (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070520) RETRY CANCEL are my only options? I'm installing the app as a service acct will ADMIN privs in AD.

Comment: RETRY or CANCEL are my only options on this splash error screen I'm installing the app as a service acct with ADMIN privs in Active Directory. the error is so cryptic I cannot make out what the root error is? I've GOOGLEC >> (HRESULT:0x80070520) with no real results.

Comment: Reposting your question as a comment doesn't help, and I've flagged it. Edit your post to share some details of your specific problem, and add formatting. If you're trying to bump it, editing will do it.

Comment: what about this? https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO22117&pmv=print&actp=PRINT&viewlocale=en_US